# How to get the mac address of all my interfaces without giving the name of interfaces?

Tags: python-3.x, windows, macos

**Environment:**

Python 3.7

MAC OS

Windows 10

**Problem:**

It exists some modules which give the mac address like [get-mac](https://pypi.org/project/getmac/) but you need to pass the name of the interface.

I would like to get the list of all mac address without knowing the names of interfaces.

I used this code below:

```
def get_mac_addresses(family):
    for interface, snics in psutil.net_if_addrs().items():
        for snic in snics:
            if snic.family == family:
                yield (interface, (snic.address))


macs = dict(get_mac_addresses(psutil.AF_LINK))
```

But I get an exception:

```
Error check subscription => module 'psutil' has no attribute 'AF_LINK'
```

So I wonder if it exists another way to get a list of existing mac on a computer MAC or Windows?

Comment: Are you sure you installed psutil module correctly? Your code runs fine for me after a fresh install of psutil. Try reinstalling that package.

Comment: You re right. It was a problem of version. I don't what happened. Pycharm downgrade my psutils. Thanks for helping.

Comment: I converted my comment to an answer, please accept :) Glad my solution worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you installed psutil module correctly? Your code runs fine for me after a fresh install of psutil. Try reinstalling that package.